# How to make to replicate this presentation and syntax highlighting using Beamer/Sweave?

Tags: beamer

Recently one of the R gurus, [Romain Francois](http://www.slideshare.net/romainfrancois/object-oriented-designs-in-r), shared his presentation on object oriented designs in R. I am wondering about following things:

1. Was this presentation made using Beamer?
2. Even if the presentation was not made using Beamer, is it possible to make something like this using Beamer? (The visual appeal of the presentation is amazing, IMHO)
3. The most important one: Can I use Sweave (I guess this is redundant if the answer to question 2 is yes)? I dont know how to get syntax highlighting in Sweave.
4. Any pointers to a template?

Thanks a lot for any pointers.

Comment: Maybe you can ask the author how he did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, yes, it was done with Beamer. Yes, it is possible to make a presentation like this with Beamer (and yes, if it was, then that may be the nicest Beamer+R+Sweave presentation I have ever seen). A person can get great syntax highlighting in R+Sweave with the SweaveListingUtils package by Peter Ruckdeschel.

I have posted some basic instructions and examples of doing Sweave+Beamer here:

http://www.ysumathstat.org/faculty/kerns/video/STAT3743/02-RESOURCES/

Mine are basic, though, just to get a person started, and do not need the optional extra highlighting. Consider also adding LyX to the mix; it can make things very easy to get up and running.

Some examples are here:

http://www.ysumathstat.org/faculty/kerns/video/STAT3743/02-RESOURCES/lectures/